# ByteLookupTable order of components (differs between JRE 7 and 8)

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, java-2d, lookup-tables

I'm using `ByteLookupTable` to apply a color lookup table to a `BufferedImage`.  Before filtering, the RGB components of each pixel in the image are the same.  Post filtering, they should be colored according to the lookup table.  All of this works as expected, except for a confusion about how to order the components going into the lookup table.

I've found that the order differs between big and little endian systems (which makes some sense), but also differs between JRE 7 and 8 on the same system.  Running the below test will produce different output between Oracle JRE 7 and 8, depending on OS.

```
OS X Java 7:    00000011 00000010 00000001 00000100
OS X Java 8:    00000100 00000001 00000010 00000011
Windows Java 7: 00000100 00000001 00000010 00000011
Windows Java 8: 00000100 00000001 00000010 00000011
Linux Java 7:   00000011 00000010 00000001 00000100
Linux Java 8:   00000100 00000001 00000010 00000011
```

My question is how can I determine which order to use, if not by simply determining the native byte order, what other info do I need to determine what order to use?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final byte[] lutArrayG = new byte[256];
        final byte[] lutArrayR = new byte[256];
        final byte[] lutArrayA = new byte[256];
        final byte[] lutArrayB = new byte[256];

        Arrays.fill(lutArrayG, (byte) 1);
        Arrays.fill(lutArrayR, (byte) 2);
        Arrays.fill(lutArrayA, (byte) 3);
        Arrays.fill(lutArrayB, (byte) 4);

        final byte[][] lutArrays = new byte[4][];

        // what is the correct order to use?  this one...
        lutArrays[0] = lutArrayG;
        lutArrays[1] = lutArrayR;
        lutArrays[2] = lutArrayA;
        lutArrays[3] = lutArrayB;

        // or this one...
        //lutArrays[1] = lutArrayG;
        //lutArrays[0] = lutArrayR;
        //lutArrays[3] = lutArrayA;
        //lutArrays[2] = lutArrayB;

        final ByteLookupTable lut = new ByteLookupTable(0, lutArrays);
        final LookupOp lutOp = new LookupOp(lut, null);
        final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        final BufferedImage imageFiltered = lutOp.filter(image, null);
        final int value = imageFiltered.getRGB(0, 0);

        System.out.println(makeNiceBinaryString(value));
    }


    public static String makeNiceBinaryString(final int value) {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(value)).replace(' ', '0'));
        sb.insert(sb.length() - 32, " ");
        sb.insert(sb.length() - 24, " ");
        sb.insert(sb.length() - 16, " ");
        sb.insert(sb.length() - 8, " ");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is my current method for determining which order to use.  It looks horrible.  The application that this comes from uses an embedded JRE 7.  However, I had a Linux user who decided to use their own Java 8 JRE -- who then encountered the bug.

```
boolean useBigEndian = ByteOrder.nativeOrder().toString().equals("BIG_ENDIAN");

if (Platform.UNIX) {
    useBigEndian = !useBigEndian; // I have no idea why this is so ???
}

if (Platform.MAC && Platform.JAVA7) {
    useBigEndian = !useBigEndian;
}

if (useBigEndian) {
    lutArray[0] = lutArrayG = new byte[256];
    lutArray[1] = lutArrayR = new byte[256];
    lutArray[2] = lutArrayA = new byte[256];
    lutArray[3] = lutArrayB = new byte[256];
} else {
    lutArray[1] = lutArrayG = new byte[256];
    lutArray[0] = lutArrayR = new byte[256];
    lutArray[3] = lutArrayA = new byte[256];
    lutArray[2] = lutArrayB = new byte[256];
}
```

How can I determine what is the correct order to use, without resorting to this messy check of system properties?

Comment: Maybe `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR`? Might be slower due to swapping.

Comment: Looks a bit as a bug "The created image is consistent with images created in the JDK1.1 and earlier releases." as specified for `TYPE_INT_ARGB`

Comment: Seems it's Java 7 that is wrong. The G, R, A, B order is just... Weird. The order of  the LUTs *should* be R, G, B, A (because there's only one band in `TYPE_INT_ARGB`, but 3 color components in the color space + 1 alpha component). This is so in both Java 1.6 and 1.8 (tested on OS X only). For `TYPE_BYTE_4ABGR`, the order is A, B, G, R (as the bands), and it's consistent across all versions. I'll try to post a sample program tomorrow, maybe someone can test on Windows/Linux. I don't think the byte order should matter.